# How to create square area with format wgs84 meters in arcgis?

Tags: format, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I can create square in a map but its dimensions are not overlap with wgs84.
For example i created 100m 100m square but map shows square's dimensions are 76.000 74.000 meters.
How can i create this square for map?
Thanks
User entering x and y values and then i got these values to create the vertices of square. But its meters are not overlap with map of wgs84 meters

```
    this.x = xInputElement.valueAsNumber;
    this.y = yInputElement.valueAsNumber;
    const { x, y } = this.mapView.center;
    this.vertices = [[x, y], [this.x + x, y], [this.x + x, -this.y + y], [x, -this.y + y]];
    this.addPolygonGraphic(this.vertices);
```

Comment: how are you creating the square? .. how are you measuring the square on creation and after? .. if you have any code, please add it to the question in order to obtain a better answer

Comment: Hi i have edited my code

Comment: I think it could be an issue related to spatial reference systems .. what is the wkid or srid of your layer and of the map?

Answer (score 0):

My mapview's spatial reference is on the image. I think it is not WGS84 but i tried that to write 4326 for spatial reference but then polygon is never creating like that [sr of mapview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLk7h.png)